# Align text vertically with an image

Tags: bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I have this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex mb-3">
    <div class="align-self-center border rounded p-2">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/16" class="float-right m-3">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With an image on right of the text. The problem is that the text and image are not aligned. How can align the text vertically in the center, so the output is this one?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you should omit the `float-right` from the image and change the order on the markup. Snippet:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex mb-3">
    <div class="align-self-center border rounded p-2">
      Text
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/16" class="m-3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a `padding-top:0.7em` to the `span tag`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex mb-3">
    <div class="row align-self-center border rounded p-2">
  <span style="float:left;padding-top:0.7em">Text</span>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/16" class="m-3"></img>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.m-3-img { margin: 0.25rem; margin-left: 0.5rem; }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex mb-3">
    <div class="align-self-center border rounded p-2">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/16" class="float-right m-3-img">
      Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```